# Jasper Report text new line when Chinese+number String overflow lose

Tags: jasper-reports

[image: This is my full String]

[image: This is Jasper report PDF file]

I use traditional Chinese ,and set the Stretch with overflow.
I find the Jasper report lose some characters like above picture when it would create a new line.

my jrxml text :

```
<textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" pattern="" isBlankWhenNull="true">
            <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" x="352" y="0" width="140" height="30" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="9855b06a-dfca-4a88-8830-efb1590c2d4e"/>
            <box topPadding="1" leftPadding="4" bottomPadding="5" rightPadding="4">
                <topPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <leftPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <bottomPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                <rightPen lineWidth="1.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
            </box>
            <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                <font fontName="標楷體" pdfFontName="MHei-Medium" pdfEncoding="UniCNS-UCS2-H" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
                <paragraph lineSpacing="Single" lineSpacingSize="1.1"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{varyReason}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
```

Do I lose some setting???

Comment: Provide sample JRXML file

Comment: this is my sample for text

Comment: are you using `Static Text` component?

Comment: sorry,i update my sample.Please help me >///<

Comment: Does this text placed at the bottom of a page? Is it ok if you are using text on English and/or another font?

Comment: No,I try it.The text will happen on the top.I use traditional Chinese "標楷體" with number will lose some characters.